# How can i use javascript to split a domain name into two variables on a form before posting?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a an input box on my homepage which i want users to input their domain to search for .
E.G.

test.com

or

test.gb.com

etc and i would like it to on submission ( post ) to extract the everything upto the first "." into a variable $domain and everything after the first including "." into $ext

So $domain might now contain "test" and $ext would contain ".gb.com" When the form was posted.

Possible ?

Here is the code for my form so far . What i need is to have everything that is inputted upto the first "." stored in the name="domain" form variable and everything in this line
        
i.e from the $ext variable stored for the form submission

Code so far :

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.jms-networks.net/domainchecker.php">
<span class="text"><input value="{php} print $_POST['sld'] ? $_POST['sld'] : 'Search for your domain name'; {/php}" type="text" name="domain" class="searchbox" onfocus="if (this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = this.defaultValue;" /></span>
<input type="hidden" name="direct" value="true" />
<!-- This one below should contain the $ext value everythign after including the first "." -->
<input type="hidden" name="tlds[]" value="what goes here???" />
<input type="hidden" name="tlds[]" value=".me.uk" />
<input type="hidden" name="tlds[]" value=".org.uk" />
<input type="hidden" name="tlds[]" value=".com" />
<input type="hidden" name="tlds[]" value=".net" />
<input type="hidden" name="tlds[]" value=".org" />

<input type="submit" value="Go" class="product-headers" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can i use jquery ? I suppose so , i'd need some help ;)

Comment: This seems pointless to me - rather than splitting it in javascript just so the server can receive it as two vars, why don't you just parse/split it in the PHP code after the server receives it and then put the pieces in two vars?

Comment: Stephen because the php code is encrypted ( WHMCS ) so i thought it easier to do in javascript etc. Maybe i'm being dumb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = $thewhole.indexOf('.');
var $domain = $thewhole.substr(0, i);
var $ext = $thewhole.substr(i);
```

Or with regexp

```
var regexp = /([^.]+)(\..*)/;
var match = regexp.exec($thewhole);
var $domain = match[1];
var $ext = match[2];
```

**Edit:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function submithelper() {

      // this is why we need the id="xxx" below.
      var $domainInput = document.getElementById("domain");
      var $extInput = document.getElementById("ext");

      var $domain = $domainInput.value;
      var $i = $domain.indexOf('.'); 
      var $host = $domain.substr(0, $i); // perhaps skip to do this if it isn't used?
      var $ext = $domain.substr($i);          

      $extInput.value = $ext;

      return true; // false to stop form from submitting.
    }

</script>

<form onsubmit="return submithelper()" method="post" action="https://www.jms-networks.net/domainchecker.php">

  <!-- Two inputs has been given IDs so we can easily get them from javascript. -->

  <span class="text"><input id="domain" value="{php} print $_POST['sld'] ? $_POST['sld'] : 'Search for your domain name'; {/php}" type="text" name="domain" class="searchbox" onfocus="if (this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = this.defaultValue;" /></span>
  <input type="hidden" name="direct" value="true" />
  <input id="ext" type="hidden" name="tlds[]" value="" />
  ...
```

Comment: Ok thankyou .. How can i add this to my form to execute on posting ?

Comment: You can add an onsubmit event handler on the form. Easiest is doing it in the HTML, but can also be done using jQuery or similar. http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_onSubmit.html

Comment: Hi Martin i have added my code for the form above. Can you help please ?

Comment: Sure, where are we? Can you paste into your post exactly as your code currently stands?

Comment: it is pasted above Martin ... Thankyou.

Comment: The second line of code is the value inputed 'domain' which needs to be stripped just leaving everything upto the first "." and the first line wirh "What goes here " should have the $ext value posted i.e everything inclucding and after the first "."

Comment: I think I got it right. I haven't run it, but it should be okay.

Comment: Fixed it ! Added line $domainInput.value = $host; below $extInput.value = $ext line. Thankyou so much Martin.